# Convert.ToInt32 behavior string vs float/double literal

Tags: c#, type-conversion

`Convert.ToInt32` behaves different when passed `string` vs `float/double` literal

```
var result = Convert.ToInt32(12.4);//returns 12
result = Convert.ToInt32(12.44);//returns 12
result = Convert.ToInt32(12.4444444);//returns 12       
result = Convert.ToInt32("12.4"); // Input string was not in a correct format.
```

I understand different overloads of `Convert.ToInt32` are being called for [string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b(v=vs.110).aspx) and [float/double](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/303w38b8(v=vs.110).aspx)

The question is why this inconsistent behavior shouldn't `single` overload for `Convert.ToInt32` throw an exception for loss of precision ?

Comment: Your first `Convert` does a type conversion from `dobule` to `int`, the equivalent of `(int)12.4`, which of course results in `12`. Your last statement internally does a `int.Parse("12.4")`, because there is no direct casting or conversion between `string` and `int`. The parsing will fail because `"12.4"` is not a valid `int` string.

Comment: They use different implementations. `Convert.ToInt32(float)` has its own implementation, but `Convert.ToInt32(String)` uses `Number.ParseInt32(String, NumberStyles, NumberFormatInfo)`. They make use of existing function. That's why the behaviour is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question is why this inconsistent behavior shouldn't single
>   overload for Convert.ToInt32 throw an exception for loss of precision
>   ?

You can think of the utility methods you're currently using to convert from `double` to `int` as *"casting"* i.e `(int)12.4`, `(int)12.44` etc. which in essence means you for sure know that there is high chance that you'll lose data precision, thus in short is like telling the compiler *"go ahead and convert it as I don't mind data loss"*, so, no exception will be thrown whereas the last example that converts from `string` to `int` *should* throw an exception because according to MSDN:

> ToInt32(String) method is equivalent to passing value to the
>   Int32.Parse(String).

and as we all know `Int32.Parse(String)` throws an exception if the specified string is not in the correct format.

Comment: thanks for the insight: *thinking of utility methods as casting*

Comment: @Winnie You're welcome. just to confirm, when I say _thinking of utility methods as casting_ I am only referring to the current situation at hand. therefore this terminology might not apply in all cases as it varies across implementations.

Answer (score 1):

You first have to convert your string into double, then cast it to int. or do another convert to int.

```
result = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDouble("12.4"));
```

From msdn `Convert.ToInt32(string)`

> Converts the specified string representation of a **number to an equivalent 32-bit signed integer**.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b(v=vs.110).aspx

In given examples you can see that converting from double representation to int gives format exception.

so this is **clearly** by design. you should do it right.

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, when you start with an `float`/`double` and you convert to `int` you expect a loss of precision. When you have a string that you convert to int you don't expect the parsing to do any losing of data, you just want it to parse and fail if the string is not valid.

Comment: Makes sense ! if only this was backed up by documentation i'd mark as answer. +1 thanks :)

Comment: Unfortunately we rarely get a glimpse into the way the .NET team arrives at certain conclusions. Method documentation  usually documents the way the method works not why they made certain design decisions. One principle they usually use is that the developer should make explicit choices about data loss, and I think that applies here. I doubt you will find something explicit documenting this decision, but if you do I would also like to see it :)